# ¿Cómo puedo obtener (al insertar/actualizar datos en varias columnas), insertar o actualizar en otra columna la suma total de cada fila?

Tags: postgresql, funciones, trigger

La operación INSERT o UPDATE se puede realizar en todas las columnas al mismo tiempo o solo en algunas de ellas.

Traté de hacerlo creando una función y su disparador, como en este ejemplo,

```
CREATE TABLE schema1.viviendas
(clase_a int,
clase_b int,
clase_c int,
clase_d int,
clase_e int,
clase_f int,
viviendas_cp int
);


--Function to run after insert or update
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema1.suma_clases()
    RETURNS trigger AS 
 $$
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO schema1.viviendas (viviendas_cp)
    values (clase_a+clase_b+clase_c+clase_d+clase_e+clase_f);
    END;
 $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


--trigger
CREATE TRIGGER insertar_total
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF clase_a, clase_b, clase_c, clase_d, clase_e, clase_f    
    ON schema1.viviendas
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE schema1.suma_clases();

--insert values
insert into schema1.viviendas (clase_a,clase_b,clase_c,clase_d,clase_e,clase_f) values
(1767,5704,3489,332,0,0);
```

Pero devuelve el siguiente mensaje:

> ERROR:  no existe la columna «clase_a»
> LINE 2:  values (clase_a+clase_b+clase_c+clase_d+clase_e+clase_f)
> ^
> HINT:  Hay una columna llamada «clase_a» en la tabla «viviendas», pero no puede ser referenciada desde esta parte de la consulta.
> QUERY:  INSERT INTO schema1.viviendas (viviendas_cp)
> values  (clase_a+clase_b+clase_c+clase_d+clase_e+clase_f)
> CONTEXT:  function PL/pgSQL schema1.suma_clases() en la línea 3 en sentencia SQL
> Estado SQL: 42703

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si entiendo bien eso que deseas lo puedes hacer usando la variable especial `NEW` dentro de la funcion`trigger` y definiendo el `trigger` como `BEFORE`

```
--Function to run before insert or update
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema1.suma_clases()
    RETURNS trigger AS 
 $$
    BEGIN
    NEW.viviendas_cp:=NEW.clase_a+NEW.clase_b+NEW.clase_c+NEW.clase_d+NEW.clase_e+NEW.clase_f;
    return NEW;
    END;
 $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


--trigger
CREATE TRIGGER insertar_total
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
    ON schema1.viviendas
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE schema1.suma_clases();

insert into schema1.viviendas (clase_a,clase_b,clase_c,clase_d,clase_e,clase_f) values
(1767,5704,3489,332,0,0);
```

si estas usando las versión 12 o superior de PostgreSQL, te recomiendo  analizar las [columnas generadas][1]

[1]: [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html#:~:text=PostgreSQL%20currently%20implements%20only%20stored,(height_cm%20%2F%202.54)%20STORED%20](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html#:%7E:text=PostgreSQL%20currently%20implements%20only%20stored,(height_cm%20%2F%202.54)%20STORED%20))%3B

Comment: Excelente, Anthony Sotolongo, funciona muy bien. Solo tuve que agregar NEW. a clase_c y clase_e. También en el cálculo, a cada clase (columna) la traté como argumento de la función COALESCE de esta forma COALESCE(clase_a,0) para evitar que si existe algún valor NULL el resultado sea NULL.

Comment: también te agradezco el enlace a las columnas generadas, el método es más sencillo (aunque con sus limitaciones). Es lo que pensé que podía existir desde un primer momento, pero había leído que solo se podía hacer usando funciones. También me funcionó generando la columna en el momento de creación de la tabla.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE schema1.viviendas
(clase_a int,
clase_b int,
clase_c int,
clase_d int,
clase_e int,
clase_f int,
viviendas_cp int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (COALESCE(clase_a,0)+COALESCE(clase_b,0)+COALESCE(clase_c,0)+COALESCE(clase_d,0)+COALESCE(clase_e,0)+COALESCE(clase_f,0)) STORED
);`

Comment: Olvidé que en tu solución hay que editar la línea ``BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF`` para declarar las columnas afectadas, en esta forma  ``BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF clase_a, clase_b, clase_c, clase_d, clase_e, clase_f``

Comment: que bueno que funciono lo edite, gracias